# I keep getting a base64 and token error what does it mean?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, encryption, runtime-error

UPDATE: I know the token error only and I don't understand what is happening as I encrypt and decrypt with the same key?
Error at hand:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback #Don't understand this callback as this is to do with the cryptography module I am using
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/PasswordManager/main.py", line 190, in see
    decrypt = f.decrypt(item[1].encode('utf-8'))
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 107, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
b'gAAAAABgY3KXoeeegS8RPHdvXTH6_GQ_EPfgdqZqIwP4XL-hIyEk3BcxV3y0o_quNPFyHeTdkv7Pk9MmnEIL1XeXlEfuUQNJ_e_dIsAr2ZvLGpDT1Y6I6Qvzat5aAf7Z0624O4BeAFNf
```

---

## Original Question

I am making a password manager, I started by using files and some suggested sqlite3 so I have started to use it so I can add the function of rewriting the passwords but I keep getting two errors that have really confused me,

The table sqlite table:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE passwords (passwordTitle text,generatedPassword text)""")
```

I encrypt the password using this function, this works and inserts into database:

```
        def submited():
            # Call the password generator
            setPassword()
            # Get user input from the entry
            usrinput = userInput.get()
            # Set a splitter for writing to the file

            # If passwordenc.txt exists:
            if os.path.isfile('data.db'):
                # Open passwordenc.txt and set it as password_file
                # Encrypt the combo
                genPasswordEnc = f.encrypt(generatePassword.encode('utf-8'))
                c.execute("INSERT INTO passwords VALUES(?,?)", (usrinput, genPasswordEnc))
                conn.commit()
            # If passwordenc.txt does not exist:
```

and I decrypt it using this function:

```
   def see():
        menu.destroy()
        seeWin = Tk()
        seeWin.geometry('1250x500')
        # Same size will be defined in variable for center screen in Tk_Width and Tk_height
        Tk_Width = 1250
        Tk_Height = 500

        # calculate coordination of screen and window form
        x_Left = int(seeWin.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - Tk_Width / 2)
        y_Top = int(seeWin.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - Tk_Height / 2)

        # Write following format for center screen
        seeWin.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x_Left, y_Top))
        seeWin.title('See Password')
        seeFrame = tk.Frame()

        listbox = tk.Listbox(seeFrame, height='30', width='135')
        listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(seeFrame, )
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
        if os.path.isfile('data.db'):

            c.execute('SELECT * FROM passwords')
            password_list = c.fetchall()
            for item in password_list:
                item = str(item)
                itemSplit = item.split(',')
                leng = len(itemSplit[1])-2
                itemCut = itemSplit[1][:leng].encode('utf-8')
                print(itemCut)
                decrypt = f.decrypt(itemCut)
                print(decrypt)
                listbox.insert(END, str(decrypt))
                print("Decrypted pass: ", decrypt)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 102, in _get_unverified_token_data
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (141) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/PasswordManager/main.py", line 190, in see
    decrypt = f.decrypt(itemCut)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 104, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

And I don't understand what is throwing this error as when using a .txt file

Comment: You are logging `itemCut`, try to log `genPasswordEnc` too. See if they are same.

Comment: The meaning of the error is obvious, an encoded string from b64encode should have length of multiple of 4 bytes.  So the b64decode function should expect an input argument with length of multiple of 4 bytes.  But in your case, it is 141 which is not an expected length.

Comment: `item` is a tuple, just use `f.decrypt(item[1].encode('utf-8'))` instead of converting it to a string and trying to find the second element in the string, which you're not doing correctly.

Comment: @AnonCoward I will try it and oh right how am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You don't account for the space between elements when converting a tuple to a string, nor do you account for any escaped characters inside the value.

Comment: @AnonCoward I now have this error:

Comment: decrypt = f.decrypt(item[1].encode('utf-8'))
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/Users/James/Documents/Programming/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 107, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken